# Homebrew world: What sort of events would keep gods from interacting in a world?

Tags: homebrew, religions-and-deities

I have a dnd world I am working on creating at the moment. It is a spinoff of the original dnd concepts. However, I have run into an issue. My big bad guy of this campaign is trying to become a lich. What sort of events would keep him from being noticed by the gods or even make him directly untouchable by the gods.

I would love to add more clarification if needed.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Mindstormer (cool name btw), take the [tour] when you have a moment. This sort of "looking for ideas" question is better suited for a more traditional forum, you can peruse our curated list [on this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). I've given you one upvote, once you have 20+ rep you will be able to participate in [chat] (you may already be able to, not sure), and maybe we can get some ideas to you there.

Comment: Rather than asking 'what _could_ prevent interference from gods' (opinion-based) you could ask 'how would gods be prevented from acting against a BBEG trying to become a lich in world X?'  This can lead to fact-based answers for a specific campaign world.  Greyhawk, Fearun, and Dark Sun all solve the 'keep the gods out' problem in different ways, and there are likely more versions in other official campaign worlds with which I am less familiar.

Comment: With some editing, this might be a good fit for Worldbuilding.SE. Also check out Dark Sun.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will look at these other areas. I am thankful for your support.